# Pipe thread to hose thread adapter

Tags: pipe, faucet, hose

I have an external faucet with a 1" (male) pipe thread. If I attach a regular hose pipe to it then (as you would expect) it leaks at that point. I would have thought that it would be easy to find a 1" pipe thread to hose thread adapter but I have been unable to do so.

Do such adapters exist? If not, what is the easiest way to connect a hose to a pipe thread faucet?

Comment: Home depot has 3/4 male pipe thread to 3/4 hose, I bought one recently. That and 1" coupler and a reducing bushing should do the trick. Don't forget to use Teflon tape (or some messy pipe dope).

Comment: An external faucet with a 1" pipe thread would be unusual, are you quite certain that's what it is?

Comment: I agree @JimmyFix-it - I was very surprised to find it. Not sure what the original intention of it was. Perhaps to hook up an irrigation system at that point?

Comment: Thanks @Tyson - I've tried them and Lowes and struck out. I'll try again.